# More posts from the current author

Tags: author, get-posts

On a multi author WordPress blog I need to show a list with more posts from the current author. The list is inside the Loop, so I can use `<?php the_author_meta('first_name'); ?> <?php the_author_meta('last_name'); ?>` and `<?php the_author_meta('description'); ?>`, but how to retrieve the user's posts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will retrieve the posts of current author when used in the loop.

Put the following in your theme functions.php:

```
function my_get_display_author_posts() {
    global $authordata, $post;

    $authors_posts = get_posts( array( 'author' => $authordata->ID, 'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID ) ) );

    $output = '<ul>';
    foreach ( $authors_posts as $authors_post ) {
        $output .= '<li><a href="' . get_permalink( $authors_post->ID ) . '">' . apply_filters( 'the_title', $authors_post->post_title, $authors_post->ID ) . '</a></li>';
    }
    $output .= '</ul>';

    return $output;
}
```

And add `echo my_get_display_author_posts();` in your template file, within the loop where you want the posts displayed.

Comment: Good answer and for users with performance in mind, you could wrap that functionality into an Ajax callback for fetching those posts **on demand**.

Comment: How would you use this outside of the loop?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the wordpress query_posts function for this.  Take a look at http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts .  This might not be enough to do what you need, but should get you started looking around the function reference.

Comment: `query_posts()` shouldn't be used for anything other than modifying main Loop. For everything else there are `get_posts()` or `WP_Query` object.

Comment: I thought in his question he said he was inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`get_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) with [Author Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Author_Parameters) (they are in `query_posts()` documentation, but these two function mostly takes same arguments).

Do not use `query_posts()` for this, it's meant for modifying main page's Loop.

Comment: I tried but without success, because this retrieves the posts from specific author. My list should show on a page with posts from many authors and I would like to show "more from this author" after/around each post of every author.

Comment: @Dimitar well the point kinda is retrieving post from specific author... If you need it several times - just retrieve several sets of post, providing different authors in parameters.