# Commenting in user profile page?

Tags: comments, users

I am trying to build custom user profile with the guidance of this tutorial: [How to make a WordPress profile page](http://blogmum.com/2009/06/how-to-make-a-wordpress-profile-page/)

I have successfully implemented it to my theme, everything is working well.
Now what I want to achieve is to get the comment template in the user profile page, where other registered user can post comment on his profile page, kinda like facebook wall or last.fm shoutbox.

I am trying it like this:

In the author page I am added this line:

```
<?php comments_template(); ?>
```

But it does not show up. 
Then I tried this way: [Get WordPress comments outside of WordPress](http://www.nkuttler.de/post/get-wordpress-comments-outside-of-wordpress/)

It adds the comment template alright but, does not work. When you click on on the submit button it redirects to a blank page.

I think the goal is not achievable easily, it requires custom database creation for each user to store the comments, since the comment system only stores comments of certain page or post, not for any other page like archive or author page.

If anyone can show me the right direction, I will be forever grateful.

Thanks
Towfiq I.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Hi **@Towfiq**:

Comments are related in the database to Posts. You'll have to do a lot of work to get Comments to relate to Users.

Have you considered creating a [Custom Post Type](http://files.meetup.com/1280797/custom-post-types-for-wordpress-atlwp-2010-10-24.html) for Users and then use either a `user_meta` field to store the `post_id`, or a `postmeta` field to store the `user_id`, or both? If you did that then you would get the comments with no effort at all.

### UPDATE

What follows is code developed after our discussion in the comments.

I've been meaning to write something like this for a long time but your question finding got me to make it a priority. I've created a `'towfiq-person'` custom post type for you and I've set it up to automatically add a Person post whenever a User is added and it uses the email address as the associating key in a post custom field called `'_email'`.

It also associates a User with an appropriate email address to the Person post if a User is added or updated with the same email as an existing Person *(this may or may not be a good idea.)* And it cross-references User with Person and Person with User using postmeta and usermeta fields `'_user_id'` and `'_person_id'`, respectively.

These are of course business rules I chose to implement but they may turn out not to be appropriate for your use-case in which case you may need to modify them.  You also may find ways that WordPress allows these two to get out of sync but it's hard to know that without exhaustive testing. If you find issues you can always look to update the logic to resolve them.

You can copy the following code to your theme's `functions.php` file:

```
class Towfiq_Person {
  static function on_load() {
    add_action('init',array(__CLASS__,'init'));
    add_action('wp_insert_post',array(__CLASS__,'wp_insert_post'),10,2);
    add_action('profile_update',array(__CLASS__,'profile_update'),10,2);
    add_action('user_register',array(__CLASS__,'profile_update'));
    add_filter('author_link',array(__CLASS__,'author_link'),10,2);
    add_filter('get_the_author_url',array(__CLASS__,'author_link'),10,2);
  }
  static function init() {
    register_post_type('towfiq-person',
      array(
        'labels'          => array('name'=>'People','singular_name'=>'Person'),
        'public'          => true,
        'show_ui'         => true,
        'rewrite'         => array('slug' => 'people'),
        'hierarchical'    => false,
        //'supports'        => array('title','editor','custom-fields'),
      )
    );
  }
  static function get_email_key() {
    return apply_filters( 'person_email_key', '_email' );
  }
  static function profile_update($user_id,$old_user_data=false) {
    global $wpdb;
    $is_new_person = false;
    $user = get_userdata($user_id);
    $user_email = ($old_user_data ? $old_user_data->user_email : $user->user_email);
    $email_key = self::get_email_key();
    $person_id = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT post_id FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} WHERE meta_key='%s' AND meta_value='%s'",$email_key,$user_email));
    if (!is_numeric($person_id)) {
      $person_id = $is_new_person = wp_insert_post(array(
        'post_type' => 'towfiq-person',
        'post_status' => 'publish',   // Maybe this should be pending or draft?
        'post_title' => $user->display_name,
      ));
    }
    update_user_meta($user_id,'_person_id',$person_id);
    update_post_meta($person_id,'_user_id',$user_id);
    if ($is_new_person || ($old_user_data && $user->user_email!=$old_user_data->user_email)) {
      update_post_meta($person_id,$email_key,$user->user_email);
    }
  }
  static function wp_insert_post($person_id,$person) {
    if ($person->post_type=='towfiq-person') {
      $email = get_post_meta($person_id,self::get_email_key(),true);
      if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $user = get_user_by('email',$email);
        if ($user) { // Associate the user IF there is an user with the same email address
          update_user_meta($user->ID,'_person_id',$person_id);
          update_post_meta($person_id,'_user_id',$user->ID);
        } else {
          delete_post_meta($person_id,'_user_id');
        }
      }
    }
  }
  static function get_user_id($person_id) {
    return get_user_meta($user_id,'_user_id',true);
  }
  static function get_user($person_id) {
    $user_id = self::get_user_id($person_id);
    return get_userdata($user_id);
  }
  static function get_person_id($user_id) {
    return get_user_meta($user_id,'_person_id',true);
  }
  static function get_person($user_id) {
    $person_id = self::get_person_id($user_id);
    return get_post($person_id);
  }
  static function author_link($permalink, $user_id) {
    $author_id = get_user_meta($user_id,'_person_id',true);
    if ($author_id) // If an associate is found, use it
      $permalink = get_post_permalink($author_id);
    return $permalink;
  }
}
Towfiq_Person::on_load();
```

If you need any clarifications to what I did and why, just ask in the comments.

Comment: So, what you are suggesting is create a custom post type and implement the loop to the author page. And then put up the comment form so that other users can post comment to that blank post? But the same comments will be shown to every users profile page. It can be avoided by creating function which will auto create custom post with the title of the username
with wp_insert_post() when a user is registered. The author of the post could be the user. So, that when we pull the loop of post we make sure the post with the author=user shows. Am I in the right direction? Am I making it complicated?

Comment: @Towfiq: Indeed, per user you create one post of your `author` custom post type. Then on the `taxonomy-author.php` template file, you also [query for all posts of the current author](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6153/more-posts-from-the-current-author), and thus "fake" your author page. You could also do it the other way around (use the author template and include the custom post), but then you need to trick the commenting form to use the right post id.

Comment: Thank for your reply Fabry. I don't have very little knowledge about taxonomy. I tried to get something out of this page:http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Custom Taxonomies display 
But failed. can you tell me what taxonomy-author.php is and what will it do? and if I try the other way around, do you have any idea about tricking the post id?? -thanks

Comment: @Towfiq: My mistake, it should not be `taxonomy-author.php`, but `single-author.php`. You don't create a custom taxonomy, but a custom post type. The `single-author.php` is the template file that is used to display a single post of the `author` custom post type. I suggest you go this way, it's the easiest (you can also use paging (`/page/2/`) if you have many posts from that author).

Comment: hmm.. Thansk! So, f I want to link author page should this work? <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?>

Comment: @Towfiq - Where do you want to place `<?php the_author_posts_link(); ?>`, i.e. in what context?

Comment: in the post page, <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?> it links to the author(profile) page.

Comment: @Towfiq - How many authors will you have?  Can you create an `'author'` custom post for each user, or do you need that to happen automatically?

Comment: what I am trying to do is making a community out of wordpress where anyone can register and registered users will have profile page. I got everything covered, except I want to create a function which will automatically create a post where the tag will be user-name. I will create a custom query like this -> query_posts('tag=$curauth->nickname;'); So, when I add the loop I will be able to use the comments_template. Needless to say the post will be blank, I will fake it. I don't know if it is possible or not... Thanks for your interest. :)

Comment: @Towfiq: Have you considered using BuddyPress with WordPress? It's designed for building communities. You might be duplicating lots of effort?

Comment: I don't want to use buddypress.. or any plugin.You see, I am a theme developer, I wan to create a theme where this feature will be added. Thanks.

Comment: @Towfiq - Ah, okay I see. I've updated my answer with a solution. Sorry for the limited explanation; I'm not feeling very good today; just ask if you have follow up questions. Also, just as a suggestion, if you can it'll probably help in the future if you tell us what you are trying to accomplish _(i.e."a commercial theme")_ as it could short-circuit lots of follow up questions on both our parts. *(P.S. I get a free copy of your theme for helping when you are done, right? ;)*

Comment: If it works, Of course you will get a free copy. and yeah it will be a commercial theme. :D Thank you so much. I will let you know if I get into trouble implementing it.

Comment: I just tried your code, I am getting "Cannot use object of type stdClass as array" when the People>Add new is clicked or when I try to create a user from Users>Add New. :(

Comment: @Towfiq - I just tested it again and it's working fine. Also, I'm not using an array anywhere in the code *(just review it so see.)* There's something in your code that's breaking. Did you verify the line number of the error was in my code, or was it instead in yours?

Comment: I am getting the error from this line:
    if ($person['post_type']=='towfiq-person') {

Comment: @Towfiq? How did I miss that when I reviewed my code? Hmm, sorry. Anyway, it should how helpful it is when you tell me where the error occurred. :) I'm also surprised it worked on my end without error. BTW, I was using a different hook before so that was remnant code. Here's what should fix it: `if ($person->post_type=='towfiq-person') {`. Let me know...

Comment: Awesome!! Worked like a charm! :) Here is how I am calling the post lke this in the author profile(author.php): http://pastebin.com/03ZhCrqW  There is a little problem though, when you click on the comment form's submit button it redirects the single post page(single.php). TO prevent that, I used this code in the functions.php   http://pastebin.com/jFY1Mj2z  The Only problem is The posts are shown everywhere, default loop, recnt post widgets, recent comments(!) DO you have any suggestion?? Thanks

Comment: @Towfiq - Can you try setting `'publicly_queryable'` and/or `'exclude_from_search'` to `false`? See:   http://codex.wordpress.org/index.php?title=Function_Reference/register_post_type&oldid=93756#Arguments

Comment: I tried them: .but no result 
'publicly_queryable' => false,
  'exclude_from_search' => true,

Comment: @Towfiq - Please, please help me help you by giving me more feedback than just to say it's not working. It is painful for me to read *"no result"* but you are not describing for me what *"no result"* means because now I have to wait again for your reply. I cannot see what you see nor can I know exactly what results you want.

Comment: So Sorry. I did not get any error. I added those tow lines right after 'post_title' => $user->display_name, but the custom posts are still added in the default loops and the wall posts(profile comments) are shown in the recent comments widget.

Comment: just tried 'public' => false that does not work too. the posts are still in default loops. Although when I add a new post from Person> Add new, the post doesn't appear in default loops.

Comment: @Towfiq - I'm confused. Some of the Person posts are appearing in the default loop but not all? And do you have any plugins that are affecting post display? Normally the loop just displays `post_type='post'`; are you sure there's not a plugin that opens that up to all post types? *(or some of your own code?)*

Comment: All the person posts are shown in the default loop and no I am not using any plugin of that sort. I have also read that the custom post types do not appear in the default loop. I will try to use it in a freshly installed wordpress and let you know.

Comment: @Towfiq - Thanks. My guess is something `post_type` is set to `'all'` in maybe a `'pre_get_posts'` hook.

Comment: Yeah it works. :D I will send you the the theme file when it is complete.

Comment: The only issue now is the comments showing up in the recent comments widget. looks like I will have to unregister the widget and create a new recent comment widget with a custom query.

Comment: @Towfiq - Awesome! Glad you finally got it worked out.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a custom post type loop inside author.php and use that custom post's comment form. I've done it many times and it works great.

```
<?php /* Display the author's comments from the custom post type (AAA) */ ?>
<?php
$authorid = get_the_author_meta( ID, $userID );
$args=array('author' => $authorid,'post_type' => 'AAA', 'numberposts' => -1);
$cquery=new WP_Query($args);
if($cquery->have_posts()):
while($cquery->have_posts()):
$cquery->the_post();
?>          
<div class="comments-area">
    <?php comments_template(); ?>
</div>
<?
    endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    endif;
?>
```

https://github.com/pjeaje/code-snippets/blob/gh-pages/GP%20author.php%20with%20multiple%20loops

Comment: Add the above above or below the author.php loop