# Wordpress for a club website -- Members page

Tags: plugin-recommendation

I'm making a website for a student activity and have a wordpress page for each member under a common parent group. Each page contains some member info (currently unstructured) and a profile picture.

I would like to list all these members under a member page with perhaps a grid of profile pictures and names. Is there a plugin that can accomplish this?

Note that each member does not have a wordpress account. I already found plugins that can do that, but it's not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider create a [custom post type](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/128/tips-for-using-wordpress-as-a-cms/187#187) `'person'` to mirror your user and then you'll be able to create member pages by creating a `single-person.php` theme template file. This answer provides code for doing that:

- [**Commenting in user profile page?**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6163/commenting-in-user-profile-page/6165#6165)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Would the information/picture for the members be contained in the posts of type `person` or in pages?

Comment: @Gus - You wouldn't use a Page for this, only a `person` custom post type. But since you are asking that question I'm guessing you don't understand the distinction?  a *"Page"* in WordPress is an element of content where the `post_type='page'` *(contrasting with a "Post" where the `post_type='post'. Confusing, I know, but it's the best they could do given legacy naming issues.)* So a *"Page"* in WordPress is not correlated to a *"web page"*, which is simply the HTML output generated by a theme template file. If I've still left you confused, please ask more questions.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I installed the "Custom Post Types" plugin and have created a `member` custom post type. Is there a way to have a structure behind a post type? For example, members have attributes like `name` and `picture`. I figure that `single-member.php` could display these fields.  I'd like to refer to these attributes when listing all the members in a members' page. Additionally, if I start writing it, how portable can I make `single-member.php` between different themes?

Comment: Gus - Creating a structure behind custom post types is a frequent requested need, and one that plugins address but not as well as I like. Check out [this resource](http://files.meetup.com/1280797/custom-post-types-for-wordpress-atlwp-2010-10-24.html) and thus far [Simple Fields](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-fields/) is probably the best I've seen.

Comment: @Gus - Rather than trying to make `single-member.php` portable across themes, create your own set of [Template Tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags) that people using your plugin can use in their templates *(I assume you are now thinking beyond this one website and want to distribute as a plugin too?)* In addition, you could add a configurable option that would append your content to the end of the content using `the_content` hook, but be sure to let themers disable it if they want to.

Comment: Many months later, I'm back to working on this! I wanted to mention that I wasn't planning on distributing a plugin, I just wanted to make sure that the template could be changed without needing to rewrite something like `single-member.php`. I was also wondering whether you still recommend Simple Fields for structured custom post types.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at BuddyPress? It's was built for Wordpress but continued to grow.  It has it's own installation and you can make a whole user community (or social network) like facebook.   It's at buddypress.org.

Hope that helps,
elaine
http://www.enzolina.com/web

Answer (score 0):

You can use Members List Plugin
The Plugin allows you to create a post on your wordpress blog that lists all your wordpress members.
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/members-list/screenshots/

But i would create a template page for that

```
    <ul id="membersList">

<?php
/*
    First we set how we'll want to sort the user list.

    You could sort them by:
    ------------------------

    * ID - User ID number.
    * user_login - User Login name.
    * user_nicename - User Nice name ( nice version of login name ).
    * user_email - User Email Address.
    * user_url - User Website URL.
    * user_registered - User Registration date.
*/

$szSort = "user_nicename";

/*
    Now we build the custom query to get the ID of the users.
*/

$listUsersID = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare(
    "SELECT $wpdb->users.ID FROM $wpdb->users ORDER BY %s ASC"
    , $szSort ));

/*
    Once we have the IDs we loop through them with a Foreach statement.
*/

foreach ( $listUsersID as $userid ) :

/*
    We use get_userdata() function with each ID.
*/

$user = get_userdata( $userid );

/*
    Here we finally print the details wanted.
    Check the description of the database tables linked above to see
    all the fields you can retrieve.

    To echo a property simply call it with $user->name_of_the_column.

    In this example I print the first and last name.
*/

    echo '<li><div class="member_item">' . ucwords( strtolower( $user->first_name . ' ' . $user->last_name ) ) . '</div></li>';

/*
     The strtolower and ucwords part is to be sure
     the full names will all be capitalized.
*/

endforeach; // end the users loop.
?>

</ul>
```