# Is it possible to add taxonomies to user profiles?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, users

I would like to know if it's possible to add taxonomies in the user profile, without hacks.

So far I have been able to add taxonomies to custom post types and all, but now I would like to add it to the user profile.

I know how to add custom fields to the user profile, but so far failed on taxonomies.

The closest I got to find a solution was: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/applying-custom-taxonomies-to-user-profiles

As a newbie trying to find it there is a better solution.

Thank you for reading and helping out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution you linked seems about right but i can't tell if its scalable and won't crash on a large scale,

another solution would be to create a non public custom post type with no UI and to act as a "stub" post for each user and keep that post ID in a user meta table, that way you can:

- make easier queries.
- use other post features for users
  like: comments,tags,categories,**custom taxonomies** and all the functionality built for posts.
- use post based plugins on a user
  profile like: voting, rating, ranking...

and i believe its a much better approach.

take a look at [Mike's answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6163/commenting-in-user-profile-page/6165#6165) to a similar question to get you started.

Comment: Thank you. I will give a go on your recommended solution. Will analyse the user meta table, so far only worked with the post meta table. I assume is more or less the same thing. Thank you Bainternet.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to read [Justin Tadlock's post](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2011/10/20/custom-user-taxonomies-in-wordpress) on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone is still looking for a similar solution, you can give a try to [User Tags Plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/user-tags/), It implements the [Justin Tadlock's Post](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2011/10/20/custom-user-taxonomies-in-wordpress) easy way.