# Enable comments for author.php

Tags: pages, comments, author, author-template

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Commenting in user profile page?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6163/commenting-in-user-profile-page)

### Question

I have an author.php page and I need to enable comments so when other users come to that authors page they could leave a short message in a form of a comment. Is that possible?

I would really appreciate any help :)